# Javascript FileReader.onload event.currentTarget.result.byteLength = 0 in Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, filereader

I am trying to read a javascript Blob by iterating through slices and recreating the blob from the slices after reading them with FileReader.  In the latest Chrome this intermittently results in either an

event.currentTarget.result.byteLength = 0

or

"A requested file or directory could not be found at the time an operation was processed."

The process is

1) Make a blob of 1 MB.

2) Slice it in 1024 byte increments one by one using callback from FileReader.onload.

3) Read each slice via FileReader and create a new Blob and save it.

4) Repeat step 2 and create a new Blob consisting of the current read and the previous one.

5) If all goes well we have an identical Blob to the original one.

This intermittently fails in Chrome.

Here is a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/jimlowrey/8koxyoft/.  Be sure to open the console viewer.

A more elaborate fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/jimlowrey/d2dL8phh/

```
<html>
<body>
Blob Test
<script>

    var end = 0, i = 0, size, newBlob = new Blob(), partBlob;

    var readSlice = function(event){
        var bytesRead = event.currentTarget.result.byteLength;
        if ( bytesRead > 0){
            newBlob = new Blob([newBlob, event.currentTarget.result]);
        }else{
            log("Zero bytes read" , event);
            return;
        }
        i = i + 1024;
        //i = i + bytesRead;
        end = i + 1024;
        if ( end > bigBlob.size ) {
            end = bigBlob.size;
        }
        if ( i < bigBlob.size){
            log("i:"+i + " end:" + end);
            read(bigBlob, i, end);
        }else{
            log(newBlob);
            log(bigBlob);
            newBlob = null;
            bigBlob = null;
        }
    };
    function read(blob, start, end){
        partBlob = blob.slice(start, end);
        log("sliced " + start + ":"+ end+", partBlob size: " + partBlob.size);
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onerror = error;
        reader.onabort = onabort;
        reader.onload = readSlice;
        reader.readAsArrayBuffer(partBlob);
    };
    function error(e){
        log("error " , e);
        log("i:" + i + " end:" + end);
    };
    function onabort(e){
        log("aborted", e);
        error(e);
    };

    function buildBlob(kb){
        var uintKbArr = new Uint8Array(1024);
        for(var i=0;i<uintKbArr.length;i++){
            uintKbArr[i]=i%256;
        }
        var blobArray = [];
        for(var i=0;i<kb;i++){
            var b = new Blob([uintKbArr]);//adds a MB each time
            blobArray.push(b);
        }
        bigBlob = new Blob(blobArray);
        return bigBlob;
    }

    function log(m, o){
        if ( o ){
            console.log(m,o);
        }else{
            console.log(m);
        }

    }
    var bigBlob = buildBlob(1024);
    size = bigBlob.size;
    log("Blob size " + size);
    read(bigBlob, 0, 1024);

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Looks like the last Chrome update, 42.0.2311.135, fixed it.

Answer (score -1):

you shoud use the `event.target.result` in place of `currentTarget` it may resolve your issue,